# Как убрать метку с первого элемента?

Tags: html, css

```
.item:before {content: '•'}
<ul>
    <li class="item" ><a href="#" >1</a></li>
    <li class="item" ><a href="#" >2</a></li>
    <li class="item" ><a href="#" >3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Подскажите, как убрать у первого LI - content: '•' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.item:first-child:before {content: '';}